# Remove/Add JMenu from/to JMenuBar

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenubar

I'm trying to remove/add a JMenu from the JMenuBar but it doesn't work.
it seems like the event used doesn't remove the JMenu from the JMenuBar.

this is the code I'm using:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Try1 {
    private JFrame mainframe;

    public Try1(){
        prepareGUI();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Try1 try1 = new Try1();
        try1.showMenuDemo();

    }
    private void prepareGUI(){
        mainframe = new JFrame("Java SWING Examples");
        mainframe.setSize(800, 400);
        mainframe.setLayout(new GridLayout(16,1));

        mainframe.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

    }

    private void showMenuDemo(){
        //create a menu bar
        final JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        JMenu CutMenu = new JMenu("Cut");
        JMenu aboutMenu = new JMenu("About");

        JMenuItem newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("New");


        final JCheckBoxMenuItem showWindowMenu = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Show Cut",true);
        showWindowMenu.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
                if(showWindowMenu.getState()){
                    System.out.println(showWindowMenu.getState());
                    menuBar.add(CutMenu);
                } else{
                    System.out.println(showWindowMenu.getState());
                    menuBar.remove(CutMenu);
                }
            }
        });
        fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);
        fileMenu.add(showWindowMenu);

        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(editMenu);
        menuBar.add(aboutMenu);
        menuBar.add(CutMenu);


        mainframe.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        mainframe.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Any Idea why it works only if a swich position of the menuBar.add(aboutMenu) with menuBar(CutMenu)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to revalidate and repaint the menu bar after making changes to it, just as you would any other container that has its components added or removed:

```
showWindowMenu.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (showWindowMenu.getState()) {
            System.out.println(showWindowMenu.getState());
            menuBar.add(CutMenu);
        } else {
            System.out.println(showWindowMenu.getState());
            menuBar.remove(CutMenu);
        }

        // ************** add this ****************
        menuBar.revalidate();
        menuBar.repaint();
    }
});
```

You don't absolutely need revalidate in this situation since the cut menu is on the end, but it's a good idea to have it, since if you remove or change a menu component that is not at the leading end, there will be a gap if you don't call `revalidate()`. You can test this by removing the about menu instead to see that `revalidate()` is needed.

Comment: Both adding and removing components in swing should automatically invalidate the component and hence also cause a repaint the next time the layout manager does its work.

Comment: @BjörnZurmaar: perhaps it should, but it doesn't, and this is the case whether we talk about menu components or more usual components, such as JButtons and the like. I think that you may be confusing what happens with a component's model is updated, such as the items within a JList or the text of a JLabel. Here a repaint is automatically called, but in the OP's case above it isn't. I invite you to test his code and test mine (which is the same but with two additional lines) and see for yourself that I speak the truth.

Comment: I did so and the revalidate is not necessary. A simple "menuBar.repaint()" at the end of itemStateChanged does the trick. Invalidation is handled by the Container class for both adding and removing items.

Comment: @BjörnZurmaar It might mark the container as "invalid", but it neither triggers a layout pass or a repaint request (has never done this since Java 1.3 in my experience), Swing updates are lazy like this, which is good, because you can add/remove any number of components without the wasting time trying to update the UI until you are ready. You manually trigger a layout pass through `revalidate`, in most cases you also want to trigger a paint pass by calling `repaint` as well

Comment: @BjörnZurmaar: read my entire answer. The `revalidate()` should be there as a force of habit, because 1) it does no harm, and 2) it is required if a middle menu component is removed, the menu bar's layout won't re-layout components, and a temporary gap will be seen, that disappears if the component is re-sized.

Comment: Didn't see the edit when I wrote the first comment. Thank you both for your hints!

Comment: @BjörnZurmaar Adding and removing components may mark the container as invalid, but that's no guarantee that it's layout will be re-calculated and you wouldn't want it to be, because layout passes are expensive to perform.  Instead, you add/remove components as you need and then trigger a single layout pass when you are ready, the layout manager API will determine, based on the "valid" state flag which containers need to be updated at that point

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add one line of code after you add/remove cut menu. You need to repaint the menubar again in order to see the changes.

```
  ` public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
     if (showWindowMenu.getState()) {
      System.out.println(showWindowMenu.getState());
      menuBar.add(CutMenu);
    } else {
      System.out.println(showWindowMenu.getState());
      menuBar.remove(CutMenu);
    }
    //This is the line to add
    menuBar.repaint();
    }
   });`
```